# How to swap columns with rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
mtcars %>%
  select(everything()) %>%  # replace to your needs
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))

#>   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1   0   0    0  0    0  0    0  0  0    0    0
```

I have the above code that counts the NA values in each column.
I want to transpose the data frame to get an output like this:

```
col_name| na_count
--------+---------
     mpg|        0
     cyl|        0
    disp|        0
      hp|        0
     ...|      ...
    carb|        0
```

How can I do this in R tidyverse syntax?

Answer (score 2):

We just need `pivot_longer` on `everything()`.  In addition, the `select` step is not needed if we are selecting all the columns.  In the new version of `dplyr` i.e. `>= 1.0.0`, instead of `summarise_all`, `summarise_at` etc, we can use `summarise` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.)))) %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'col_name', values_to = 'na_count')
```

---

In `base R`, it can be more compact

```
stack(colSums(is.na(mtcars)))[2:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done in tidyverse using gather, as you are looking to transpose the columns to rows.

```
mtcars %>% 
gather(key = col_name, value= col_values) %>% 
group_by(col_name) %>% 
summarise(na_count = sum(is.na(.)))
```

Should give:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   col_name na_count
   <chr>       <int>
 1 am              0
 2 carb            0
 3 cyl             0
 4 disp            0
 5 drat            0
 6 gear            0
 7 hp              0
 8 mpg             0
 9 qsec            0
10 vs              0
11 wt              0
```